# Django admin page adding save as pdf button

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In the below code I have added a save as pdf button in admin page by customizing it. While I'm clicking the save as pdf button it should display the details of the current page in pdf format. I'm not able to retrieve the separate data of the current page to display it in the pdf form (`my_template.html`). How to do it? Thanks in advance.

`views.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.db import models
from details.utils import render_to_pdf #created in step 4
from .models import UserDetails

class GeneratePdf(View): 
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      #THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I GET STUCK
      all = {
          "Name": "obj.name",
          "Email": "obj.email",
          "Address": "obj.address",
          "DOB": "obj.dob",
          "Gender": "obj.gender",
      } 
      pdf = render_to_pdf('my_template.html', all)
      return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

`urls.py`:

```
"""myapp URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from details.views import GeneratePdf
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^pdf/$', GeneratePdf.as_view(),name='generatepdf'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anton Shurashov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45755622) is correct. In addition to that, in the template while specifying the URL in the required tag, you should know the ID of the data to access it. It will work only when the data is saved in the database.

```
{%url 'generatepdf' adminform.form.instance.id  %}
```

`"""adminform.form.instance.id"""` is the general instance indicating the ID of the current page data.

The button should be visible only after saving the data.

Answer (score 1):

`urls.py`:

```
from details.views import GeneratePdf

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^pdf/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', GeneratePdf.as_view(), name='generatepdf'),
]
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.db import models
from details.utils import render_to_pdf
from .models import UserDetails

class GeneratePdf(View): 
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = UserDetails.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('user_id'))
        all = {
            "Name": obj.name,
            "Email": obj.email,
            "Address": obj.address,
            "DOB": obj.dob,
            "Gender": obj.gender,
        } 
        pdf = render_to_pdf('my_template.html', all)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'generatepdf' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pdf/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: I am getting the above error while executing based on your idea.

Comment: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'generatepdf' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pdf/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: I assume that somewhere in your template you have something like `{% url 'generatepdf' %}`. Change It on `{% url 'generatepdf' user_id %}` where `user_id` is a variable with an id of a user.

Comment: Again it is showing me the same error.Tell me how you are setting the parameter as user_id? what does it refer to?

Comment: I tried what you said but it giving me the same error. Then I got getting it but it is not dynamic.{% url 'generatepdf' user.id %} I did like this and it is static.How to change it dynamically?

Comment: @Prasannavasu `user.id` is a simple variable, you set it in your template context like other variables. This is an example from django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names

Comment: Thank you so much.I finally got it dynamically.What I did is...{%url 'generatepdf' adminform.form.instance.id  %}

Comment: Even though I placed ´{%url 'generatepdf' adminform.form.instance.id %}´ in `my_template.html`, I still get the error. @AntonShurashov

Comment: @filtfilt hello, please create a new question with your code and full stacktrace of the error, because you could have the different case